# I'm having weird rigging problems with this model i was trying to rig

Tags: rigging

im currently very new to modeling and rigging and i've been struggling to fix these weird problems with the model where other parts of the model move when i move something like the arms or legs. I have tried weight painting, but it has not helped, ive put an image below.

[image: the first panel is the model with the rig, the second one is how when i move the leg forward, a small part of the tail goes down. the third image showing how when its going back, the part of the tail goes into the model. the last image shows how the eyes slightly move when moving the arms.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the vertices that don't work correctly, remove them from all groups:

[image]

Then assign them to the correct vertex group:

[image]